# "A myriad of emotions 'greet/greets' me"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

Here, "myriad" is a noun, and I suppose "myriad of emotions" is a prepositional phrase, so presumably the verb must agree with "myriad"?

Comment: Have a look at [*a battery of tests is/are*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226075/a-battery-of-tests-is-are/226125#226125). It has a very long answer. Can't read it this early in the morning, but it probably answers your question.

Comment: *Of emotions* is a prepositional phrase. *Myriad of emotions* is a noun phrase. Otherwise you suppose correctly.

Comment: Is _greets_ even a word?  Greet, Greeted, Greeting, Greetings, Can't find Greets.

Comment: @JoeDark: "greets" is the third person singular present tense form of the verb "to greet."

Comment: Relevant: [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378). That question mentions "a myriad of," but the answers don't address it. However, the example of "a number of questions have been asked" shows that the verb does not always have to agree with the first noun in constructions with "of."

Comment: A prepositional phrase starts with a preposition, so the only thing that could be a prepositional phrase is "of emotions," not "myriad of emotions." You may know this already; in that case, there's a typo in your post.

Answer (score 0):

"Myriad" in this context is a collective noun. Numerous sources agree that collective nouns may take the singular or plural, depending on context.

(blog.dictionary.com; bbc.grammar;blog.oxforddictionaries.com etc)